# string manipulation: remove last component of path

Tags: linux, string, bash

Here is my code

```
real_path="/u1/h7/user/469/code/hw4/b.sh"
while [ "$real_path" != "/" ]
do
  echo $real_path
  real_path=${real_path%/*}
done
echo $real_path   #just to print the root '/'
```

I would like my script to print following lines but the `real_path=${real_path%/*}` seems not working, any suggestion or other way to implement this?

```
/u1/h7/user/469/code/hw4/b.sh
/u1/h7/user/469/code/hw4
/u1/h7/user/469/code
/u1/h7/user/469
/u1/h7/user
/u1/h7
/u1
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `dirname`:

```
#! /bin/bash

real_path="/u1/h7/user/469/code/hw4/b.sh"
while [ "$real_path" != "/" ];do
    echo "$real_path"
    real_path=$(dirname "$real_path")
done
echo "$real_path"
```

Output:

```
/u1/h7/user/469/code/hw4/b.sh
/u1/h7/user/469/code/hw4
/u1/h7/user/469/code
/u1/h7/user/469
/u1/h7/user
/u1/h7
/u1
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using:

```
${real_path%/*}
```

It will finally strip `/u1` to an empty string hence `real_path` will never by equal `/` and you will run an infinite loop.

To **fix**, use code like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

real_path="/u1/h7/user/469/code/hw4/b.sh"

while [[ -n "$real_path" ]]; do
   echo "[$real_path]"
   real_path="${real_path%/*}"
   parent="$real_path/"
done

echo "final: [$parent]";
```

This will print:

```
[/u1/h7/user/469/code/hw4/b.sh]
[/u1/h7/user/469/code/hw4]
[/u1/h7/user/469/code]
[/u1/h7/user/469]
[/u1/h7/user]
[/u1/h7]
[/u1]
final: [/]
```

Comment: thanks! I wasn't thinking! anyway you suggest how I can go up a directory?

Comment: I'd like my last output be the parent directory of u1, which is the root. Not null....

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
real_path="/u1/h7/user/469/code/hw4/b.sh"
while [ "$real_path" != "" ];do 
      echo "$real_path"          
      real_path=${real_path%/*}     
done
```

Comment: Your `for` loop is wrong! (not mentioning it's useless if `real_path` doesn't contain spaces or glob characters—and if it does, you'll see why it's wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of achieving your desired output using awk to split the path on `/`:

```
$ awk -F'/' '{while(NF-->2)print;print FS}' OFS='/' <<<"/u1/h7/user/469/code/hw4/b.sh"
/u1/h7/user/469/code/hw4
/u1/h7/user/469/code
/u1/h7/user/469
/u1/h7/user
/u1/h7
/u1
/
```

`NF` is the number of fields. By decreasing the value, the last field is removed from the output. The final `print` prints the Field Separator `FS`, which has been defined as `/`. This could be seen as a bit of a cheat but then again, all your paths probably have `/` as the parent directory.

Comment: yea it could be seen as a bit of a cheat just like I could print a '/' at the end but thanks for replying! I just learned how to use awk, thanks

Comment: No problem. I guess the issue arises because the final output is the only one with a trailing slash. If they all had one, it would be possible to treat them all in the same way.